# NSString to JSON string

Tags: ios, json, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I have a `NSString` with below format .Currently it is not a valid JSON string .I want to change it as a JSON string and store it in an `NSArray`.
This is my `NSString.`

```
[, {"Agent":" Visitor", "Time":"03:18 AM", "Message":"Msg from : file:///Users/satheesanop/Desktop/something.htmlIP Address : 182.72.139.142Country : IndiaCity : MadrasRegionName : Tamil N?duBrowser : Chrome 22OS : Mac", }, {"Agent":" agent name", "Time":"03:21 AM", "Message":"Thank you for contacting us.How may i help you ?", }, {"Agent":" Visitor", "Time":"03:22 AM", "Message":"Some message.", }]
```

Any help is appreciated .

Comment: If possible, you should fix the server to provide you with a valid JSON string, because parsing **this** won't be fun.

Comment: valid json format is : [
    {
        "Agent": " Visitor",
        "Time": "03:18 AM",
        "Message": "Msg from : file:///Users/satheesanop/Desktop/something.htmlIP Address : 182.72.139.142Country : IndiaCity : MadrasRegionName : Tamil N?duBrowser : Chrome 22OS : Mac"
    },
    {
        "Agent": " agent name",
        "Time": "03:21 AM",
        "Message": "Thank you for contacting us.How may i help you ?"
    },
    {
        "Agent": " Visitor",
        "Time": "03:22 AM",
        "Message": "Some message."
    }
]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to convert `NSString` to `NSData` using `dataUsingEncoding:` method.

then use the `JSONObjectWithData` method and add it to array.

```
NSArray *arrayJson = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil],nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out ..

```
Mystr = [Mystr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[,"  withString:@"["];
Mystr = [Mystr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@", }" withString:@"}"];
```

Thanks Everybody.