# converting my nsstring to json

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing

I am new to json and confuse how to do this. I have this basic info below i need to convert

```
    "trailer":
         "window":"broken"
         "sidesteps":"dent"
    "tractor":
        "window":"craked"
        "sidesteps":"missing"
     "tire":
        "tire1":
            "pressure":"120"
            "rim":"good"
         "tire2":
            "pressure":"120"
            "rim":"good"
```

Comment: How does window=broken differ from rim:good?  its unclear why sometimes you are using : and others = to show the relationship

Comment: i edited now the info, the trailer tractor and tire are objects with value inside. how or what will i use to convert this to json and pass to the server

Comment: @baste, How are you creating the above string? Is it created programmatically? Was that a dictionary before conversion?

Comment: @ACB actually its just a draft of my information to be sent.  i will pullout the values from a textfield. the above string is just a presentation for us. i need to know how can i achieve this format (if this is a right json format) given that the values will come from a textfield or another string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSString to JSON string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139483/nsstring-to-json-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a dictionary from all the values you fetched from textFields. It will look like this,

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"trailer":@{@"window":@"broken", @"sidesteps":@"missing", @"tractor": @{@"window":@"broken",@"sidesteps":@"missing"}, @"tire":@{@"tire1" : @{@"pressure" : @"120", @"rim":@"good"}}}};
```

Output:

```
dictionary =   {
        "trailer": {
            "window": "broken",
            "sidesteps": "missing",
            "tractor": {
                "window": "broken",
                "sidesteps": "missing"
            },
            "tire": {
                "tire1": {
                    "pressure": "120",
                    "rim": "good"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You can use `NSMutableDictionary` to create a similar structure dynamically. You can create multiple mutable dictionaries and add it as an object of another dictionary to achieve the above result.

To convert to JSON data you can do this,

```
NSError *error;
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
```

If you want to convert to a string to view the data,

```
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:postData encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy];
NSLog(@"jsonString = %@", jsonString);
```

If you want to set this postbody to http request and pass it to server, you can set it as,

```
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
```

Comment: Of course, this doesn't tell him how to create the "real" (dynamic) dictionary structure.  (And the Apple JSON API sucks because it creates an NSData rather than going straight to NSString.  Better to use one of the open source versions.)

Comment: That was just an example of how to convert to JSON. If the question is to create dictionary, I shall include that as well.

Comment: @ACB3 you're the best! thank you this is very helpful. i will try to check the dictionary you mentioned but this is already a big help. If only i can vote :) my reputation is below 15 still :(, but thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know that's not legal JSON, and it's just supposed to be a schematic representation, it represents a set of nested NSDictionary objects. The outer dictionary contains keys "trailer", "tractor", and "tire", and each of those corresponds to an NSDictionary. The NSDictionary for "trailer" has keys "window" and "sidesteps". The others are similar, only "tire" has another level of NSDictionary nesting.

As to getting the values from a text field, that's up to you.  What is your UI design like?  If those are fixed fields (the key values are always the same) then you can just have the user fill in multiple text fields in a list.

Comment: i agree with your explanation