# Convert text into json in Objective c

Tags: ios, json

I have a string that I want to convert it into JSON in iOS but it is returning `nil` when I'm parsing it using `jsonkit`. My string format is as follows.

```
[
    { index:0, title:ARPPU },
    { index:1, title:ARPU },
    { index:2, title:Conversion },
    { index:3, title:DAU },
    { index:4, title:DAU },
]
```

Any one have idea how I can convert into a JSON object? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can use `NSJSONSerialization`.

Comment: Please show how you're doing the JSON serialization.

Comment: #import "JSONKit.h"
...
NSDictionary *myDictionary = [myString objectFromJSONString];

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139483/nsstring-to-json-string

Comment: Try this may be help-full ....
http://www.jogendra.com/2013/07/json-nsdata-to-nsdictionary.html

Comment: Yes i got solution. Actually problem is in my json string. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I would see here is your JSON string is invalid. Validate your JSON [here](http://jsonlint.com/)

Try this

```
 NSString *strJson = @"[{\"index\": \"0\",\"title\": \"ARPPU\"}]";
    id jsonObj = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[strJson dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] 
                                              options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

This worked for me.

Comment: There is an error: The JSON has a top element of an array but the code is assigning the result to a dictionary, it should be an array.

Comment: @Zaph You are right. It returns an id which holds an array.

Comment: Best practice, do not use `id` when the type is known.

Comment: Then what should be used when type is unknown?

Comment: If the type is unknown how is it going to be accessed. In short the type should, really must, be known. In this case it is an array. Note that the standard default is a dictionary so in general your initial code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

First fix the JSON string, see [Introducing JSON](http://json.org) and [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp).

Then it is a JSONstring representation.

Convert to NSData and use `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:`

```
NSString *JSONStringRepresentation= @"["
@"{ \"index\":0, \"title\":\"ARPPU\" },"
@"{ \"index\":1, \"title\":\"ARPU\" },"
@"{ \"index\":2, \"title\":\"Conversion\" },"
@"{ \"index\":3, \"title\":\"DAU\" },"
@"{ \"index\":4, \"title\":\"DAU\" },"
@"]";

NSData *JSONAsData = [JSONStringRepresentation dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error;
NSArray *JSONAsArrayObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONAsData  options:0 error:&error];
NSLog(@"JSONAsArrayObject: %@", JSONAsArrayObject);
```

NSLog output:

> JSONAsArrayObject: (
>       {
>           index = 0;
>           title = ARPPU;
>       },
>           {
>           index = 1;
>           title = ARPU;
>       },
>           {
>           index = 2;
>           title = Conversion;
>       },
>           {
>           index = 3;
>           title = DAU;
>       },
>           {
>           index = 4;
>           title = DAU;
>       }   )

Answer (score 0):

Convert your string to NSData with NSUTF8Encoding and do a JSONSerialisation to make it JSON

```
// Converting Your String to NSData
NSString *myString=@"[
{ index:0, title:ARPPU },
{ index:1, title:ARPU },
{ index:2, title:Conversion },
{ index:3, title:DAU },
{ index:4, title:DAU },
]";
// Converts the string to Data 
NSData* data = [myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
// Does JSONSerialisation and convert the data into JSON
NSDictionary*dict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
// Prints here the JSON 
NSLog(@"Dict value==%@",dict);
```

Comment: There is an error: The JSON has a top element of an array but the code is assigning the result to a dictionary, it should be an array. Also the JSON is invalid, strings must be quoted.